# pandas if full string contained in another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'd like to categorise parts using dataframes.

Simplifying the problem to try and show the issue:

```
data = {'col1': ['engine','blue engine cover','spark plug',
        'rear panel','black rear panel', 'blue engine']}
desc_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

catg = {'bodywork': ['engine cover','side panel','rear panel'],'underhood':['engine','spark plug','oil filter'],
   'Glass':['Windscreen','window','demister']}

catg_df = pd.DataFrame(data=catg)

catg_df


   Glass         bodywork       underhood
0 Windscreen     engine cover   engine 
1 window         side panel     spark plug 
2 demister       rear panel     oil filter 

desc_df

     col1
0   engine 
1 blue engine cover 
2 spark plug 
3 rear panel 
4 black rear panel 
5 blue engine
```

I would like to end up with :

```
  col1                Category
0 engine              underhood 
1 blue engine cover   underhood 
2 spark plug          underhood 
3 rear panel          bodywork 
4 black rear panel    bodywork 
5 blue engine         underhood
```

The closest I have come up with is:

```
d=catg_df.apply('|'.join).to_dict()

desc_df['Category'] = desc_df['col1'].apply(lambda x : ''.join([z if pd.Series(x).str.contains(y).values else '' for z,y in d.items()]))
```

But I end up with finding both "engine" and "engine cover" in the string:
         desc_df

```
col1                   Category
0 engine              underhood 
1 blue engine cover   bodyworkunderhood 
2 spark plug          underhood 
3 rear panel          bodywork 
4 black rear panel    bodywork 
5 blue engine         underhood
```

Is there some method I could use to perhaps if it finds "engine Cover" first then categorises using this category and does not move onto "engine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by iterating your dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([(k, '|'.join(catg_df[k].tolist())) for k in catg_df.columns[::-1]])

for k, v in d.items():
    desc_df.loc[desc_df['col1'].str.contains(v), 'Category'] = k
```

**Result**

```
print(desc_df)

                col1   Category
0             engine  underhood
1  blue engine cover   bodywork
2         spark plug  underhood
3         rear panel   bodywork
4   black rear panel   bodywork
5        blue engine  underhood
```

**Explanation**

- For each item in your dictionary, check your `str.contains` condition versus regex value and assign key to 'Category' column.
- Use `collections.OrderedDict` to give priority to columns.
- In this case, it is possible to reverse the iteration order of columns in construction of `d`.

Answer (score 3):

One way may be to use `difflib` to get closest value and `lambda`:

First creating a mapper:

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
mapper = {val:k for k, v in catg_df.to_dict('list').items() for val in v}
print(mapper)
```

So, mapper would be as:

```
{'Windscreen': 'Glass',
 'demister': 'Glass',
 'engine': 'underhood',
 'engine cover': 'bodywork',
 'oil filter': 'underhood',
 'rear panel': 'bodywork',
 'side panel': 'bodywork',
 'spark plug': 'underhood',
 'window': 'Glass'}
```

Now, using `lambda` with `difflib` to find the closest value:

```
# avoid calling mapper.keys() in lambda 
keys = mapper.keys()
desc_df['Category'] = desc_df['col1'].apply(lambda row: mapper[get_close_matches(row, keys)[0]])
```

Result:

```
                col1   Category
0             engine  underhood
1  blue engine cover   bodywork
2         spark plug  underhood
3         rear panel   bodywork
4   black rear panel   bodywork
5        blue engine  underhood
```